# Equivalent of Lambda "Any" clause in Fluent NHibernate Queryover

Tags: c#, lambda, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I want to know what is a ***Equivalent of Lambda "Any" clause in Fluent NHibernate Queryover***?

for example in lambda we write such codes

```
 cases = cases.Where(@case => @case.Assignments.Any(assignment => assignment.IsActive));
```

How can I implement this in Queryover?

Comment: `count > 0` is the same as "Any"

Comment: What is the type of 'Assignments'? FYI, '.Count()' is not the same as '.Any()'?

Comment: I would assume the above does an Exists query for the `.Any` portion of the Linq statement.  I would recommend taking a look at the sql output above by that and maybe reverse engineering it from the outputted SQL.  It may be easier to think in those terms than by looking at just the Linq.